# MySQL Average Function not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get average of the total amount for only those orders starting from 1st January 2015. Somehow, I am not getting the expected the result.

**Problem Statement: Return for each customer their id, name and average total order 
     amount for orders starting on January 1, 2015 (inclusive). Only show customers that have placed at least 2 orders.**

Since there are multiple conditions involved, I have created the query including where, group by and having clause as shown in the query below

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, AVG(o.total)
FROM db_order.Customer c JOIN db_order.orders o 
on c.customerId = o.customerId
where o.orderDate >= 01-01-2015 
group by o.CustomerId, c.CustomerName
having count(o.orderId) >= 2
```

The expected output has 6 rows and actual has 8. And there is a difference in returned results even in the average total.

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d872bf
**Db Fiddle** with complete data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd6fcb2a41634b0e4beb8acc3288e922

Comment: Hi @sunny93 can we see some data ? Thanks!

Comment: could you add some example data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sure, here is the schema
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d872bf

Comment: @sunny93 - and data?

Comment: unable to add data, it says too large

Comment: switch to dbfiddle.uk and reduce data if possible to the relevant bits

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd6fcb2a41634b0e4beb8acc3288e922

Comment: added complete data

Comment: You say: "The expected output has 6 rows and actual has 8" but I see 13 rows when I enter your query ... after I have edited some errors...

Comment: Oh sorry, i have been playing around with it so that's why the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this resolve your problem:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId
       , c.CustomerName
       , AVG(o.total)
FROM Customer c 
JOIN Orders o on c.customerId = o.customerId
where o.orderDate >= '2015-01-01' 
group by o.CustomerId
      , c.CustomerName
having count(o.orderId) >= 2
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a43efcea58080e7522279390add42702)
Showing 6 rows as asked...